# Writing an MBR from inside windows

Tags: windows-7, bootloader

I assumed that this would be simple, but it turns out not to be the case.

I wish to create an MBR/bootloader record that simply points to the installation of windows that is actually running at the moment.

I got it running by using something called Super Grub Disk, but the default windows startup repair finds the installation (right name, size, etc) but cannot seem to do this.

Right now, the windows bootloader seems to think that everything is OK, but a broken version of GRUB or something similar is sitting in the way, preventing the bootloader from ever getting run normally (I have no idea how Super Grub Disk works, but it probably just scans that partitions)

Any ways of doing this?

Comment: Try bcdboot command from windows

Comment: With what options? Tried the first example, now testing

Comment: Just use bcdboot c:\windows

Comment: Does not work, sorry

Comment: Hmm. Maybe bcdboot is trying to access files that are in use by your windows instance.

Comment: It succeeds, just does not work.

Comment: Have you tried to repair the windows? YOu can easily [restore windows MBR](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html).

Comment: Yes, and no dice. Plus, that is not the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but [EasyBCD](http://download.cnet.com/EasyBCD/3000-2094_4-10556865.html?tag=posts;msg3325506) and/or [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html) and/or [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392) might do the trick.

Comment: Not sure why EasyBCD does not have a link that says it is free for home use on their site (least I didn't see it).